# OPENAI - AZURE SSL error certification verification error

Tags: azure, ssl, openai-api

whenever i make a request to azure-openai to create some embeddings the result is the error:

```
Error communicating with OpenAI: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='form-chatgpt-open-ai.openai.azure.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: //openai/deployments/embedding_01/embeddings?api-version=2023-03-15-preview (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1007)')))
```

if needed i can provide the code

i really don't know how to solve this. i am not behind any vpn, tried to use other wi-fis. has anyone encountered the same problem?

Answer (score 2):

Codemakers215 answer will not work with openAI > 1.0 anymore.
It switched over to use http_client as extra parameter and used httpx under the hood. This gives us more flexibility and not have to change the source anymore.

Also the azure parameters changed a bit.

To use it first install

```
pip install httpx[http2]
```

**Option 1: Disable SSL check**

```
from langchain.schema import AIMessage, HumanMessage
from langchain.chat_models import AzureChatOpenAI

azure_configs ={      
    "azure_endpoint" : "https://<your oai url>.openai.azure.com/",
    "openai_api_version" :"2023-07-01-preview",
    "azure_deployment" : "<your deployment name>",
    "openai_api_key" :"your key",
    "openai_api_type" :"azure",
    "http_client": httpx.Client(verify=False)
}
llm = AzureChatOpenAI(**azure_configs)
result = llm( [HumanMessage(content='Tell me about pluto')])
```

**Option 2: Use custom certs from the CA Store**

When you are behind a firewall or your Company uses custom certs, or you use venv and don't have all the certs in your store, you have to

1. export the cert from the browser based on your azure url (see solution above)
2. attach it to the CA Store (see solution above)

At that point you can check if the default response is working again

```
url ="https://platform.openai.com/" # or your azure url
response = requests.get(url)
```

The issue is still with openai module. The default httpx setting does not uses the requests.certs path. That's where you can just send it through via:

```
requests.certs.where()
```

All together:

```
from langchain.schema import AIMessage, HumanMessage
from langchain.chat_models import AzureChatOpenAI

azure_configs ={      
    "azure_endpoint" : "https://<your oai url>.openai.azure.com/",
    "openai_api_version" :"2023-07-01-preview",
    "azure_deployment" : "<your deployment name>",
    "openai_api_key" :"your key",
    "openai_api_type" :"azure",
    "http_client": httpx.Client(verify=requests.certs.where())
}
llm = AzureChatOpenAI(**azure_configs)
result = llm( [HumanMessage(content='Tell me about pluto')])
```

Answer (score 1):

For later versions of the openai python library, I found that you can pass a httpx client into the AzureOpenAI and OpenAI class for client creation:

I had to install the httpx library to get it working.

```
pip install httpx[http2]
```

Client creation:

```
import openai
import httpx

# Create an httpx client and pass the SSL certificate path or set to False
httpx_client = httpx.Client(http2=True, verify=False)

azure_client = openai.AzureOpenAI(
    api_key="##############################",
    api_version="2023-07-01-preview",
    azure_endpoint="https://example.openai.azure.com/",
    http_client=httpx_client
)

openai_client = openai.OpenAI(
    api_key="##############################",
    http_client=httpx_client
)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Error communicating with OpenAI:HTTPSConnectionPool(host='form-chatgpt-open-ai.openai.azure.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: //openai/deployments/embedding_01/embeddings?api-version=2023-03-15-preview (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1007)')))

The above error occurs whether behind firewall or VPN and also the problem frequently arises when the API endpoint's SSL certificate cannot be verified.

You can disable the SSL certificate by using (verify=false) in your API request but it is not recommended in a production environment.

You can use the below Python code to create an embedding request.

```
import openai      
openai.api_type = "azure" openai.api_key = YOUR_API_KEY
openai.api_base = "https://YOUR_RESOURCE_NAME.openai.azure.com"
openai.api_version = "2023-05-15"

response = openai.Embedding.create(input="Good evening my friend!!!",
    deployment_id="Your deployment name",
    model="text-embedding-ada-002",
    verify=False)
embeddings = response['data'][0]['embedding']
print(embeddings)
```

**Output:**

```
[-0.011282265186309814, -0.03910282626748085, -0.008493438363075256, -0.001599661074578762, 0.007867115549743176, -0.008391872979700565, 0.0427253395318985, 0.031857799738645554, 0.025103675201535225, 0.0071138362400233746, -0.042285218834877014, -0.00586965586990118, 0.013516712002456188, -0.016546757891774178, 0.004409647546708584, 0.016301307827234268, -0.017020732164382935, 0.016538294032216072, 0.007228097878396511, 0.03163773939013481, 0.008654250763356686, -0.010765972547233105, -0.026847220957279205, 0.003654252039268613, -0.008425727486610413, -0.003529410809278488, 0.00015380338300019503, 0.008125262334942818, 0.002232331084087491, 0.006132034119218588]
```

[image]

**Reference:**

- [How to generate embeddings with Azure OpenAI Service - Azure OpenAI | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/openai/how-to/embeddings?tabs=python)
- Similar issue-[APIConnectionError: Error communicating with OpenAI · Issue #56 · openai/openai-python · GitHub](https://github.com/openai/openai-python/issues/56)

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same error while using Azure openAI and Langchain with openAI.

`verify=False` does not work for API calls in following format:

```
openai.Completion.create(
            engine="text-davinci-003",
            prompt=prompt,
            max_tokens=200,
            n=1,
            temperature=0.9,
            verify=False
        )
```

While using python, all we require to do is edit the `api_requestor.py` file in ./site-packages/openai/

Search for the function `request_raw` and add `verify=False` in the request as shown below.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
os.environ['REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE'] = certifi.where()
ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context()
ssl_context.check_hostname = True
ssl_context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
client = httpx.Client(verify=ssl_context)

And set the client  as a parameter to AzureChatOpenAI 
http_client=client

azure_chat_openai = AzureChatOpenAI(
temperature=0,
max_tokens=1024,
# openai_api_base=openai.base_url,
azure_endpoint=openai.base_url,
openai_api_version=openai.api_version,
deployment_name=chat_deployments[model].get('model'),
openai_api_key=openai.api_key,
openai_api_type=openai.api_type,
http_client=client,
streaming=True
)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**